# Rails app in Production doesn't load images?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I just prepped my production server running Ubuntu 17.04, Apache2, Passenger, latest Ruby and Rails.
When I browse my site, images used in CSS as background images do not load:

```
.firstrow {
  background-image: url("backdrop2.png");
}
```

Error: http://server.lan/assets/backdrop2.png

I guess I have to use a more FQDN in CSS to fetch the image, but how come it works in dev? And what path should I use in CSS?
I should also mention that I use SASS.

Comment: Error png doesn't load??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [image-url helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).  If you are using Sass, you can replace your code with this:

```
.firstrow { background-image: image-url("backdrop2.png"); }
```

This of course assumes your image is in one of Rails' image [assets search paths](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization).  By default, the Rails asset pipeline will search for your images in:

- `app/assets/images`
- `lib/assets/images`
- `vendor/assets/images`

Also, make sure your deployment script runs `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` on your production server.  Many do automatically, but not all.

Comment: Yes my image is in the default asset path, in dev I works but not in Prod. Been reading image-url helper link and there is good help there so thank you! I have tried your example but that did not do the trick.

Comment: You may have a configuration problem in the asset pipeline.  You may need to make sure your deployment script runs bundle exec rake assets:precompile. Most do automatically, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

The asset path used should be more dynamic to support both the enviroments.

```
body {
  background: asset_url('background-image.png')
}
```

Try running `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` , in production environment as default assets(eg. images) are searched in public/assets folder.

Open firebug and check the path of image reference when the DOM element containing the image path loads up in page, also refer the logs to check the final path accessed and relate with the missing assets.

Comment: Firebug says that the image should be here: 
    background-image: url(/assets/backdrop2-e520bf1d924511528644ee0c81f6a3aae55c23b5520aafcc6b56a199a16b52d2.png);

That is a step forward but still no image.

Comment: Well... after compiling the sass locally and pushing that to the server all hell broke loose.

Comment: Well... after compiling the sass locally and pushing that to the server all hell broke loose.
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in `asset_path'
3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:137:in `asset_url'

Comment: Ok... I left the problem 2 hours ago, thought I would take a look at it again and now it works... what the... using image-url so I guess I'll set that as the solution.